# How to check if your form is already opened or not and close it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form named as outobjects.cs it can launch every 5 mins, So after I can launch any of them I need to check if outobjects.cs open or not and close it.

Comment: Launch a form name ***.cs
What does that mean? Can you show the code in which you launch it?

Comment: Your Form name is not actually outobjects.cs (perhaps outobjects, but even then it doesn't need to be). The name of an object is not the same thing as the name of the source code file (even ignoring the extension). What have you tried? Where are you running into issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms have a `.Visible` property that is `true` if the form is visible.

Declare your form inside the class:

```
private OutObjects outObjects;
```

Initialize/launch it:

```
outObjects = new OutObjects();
outObjects.Show();
```

and later if you want to close it if it's open check the `.Visible` property:

```
if (outObjects != null && outObjects.Visible)
    outObjects.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to avoid opening the same form more then once.

If you want to get all Open Forms, look no further then [Application.OpenForms()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms). It lists all Forms that have been opened but were not yet closed. A simple `is` check will find any instance of the "UniqueForm" class, if it is already opened. Do note the unique collection type it has, as it comes from the old pre-generics days. You also should not use foreach to itterate over it - as you are planning to change the collection and foreach does not like that.

```
var OpenFormsReference = Application.OpenForms();
bool foundForm = false;

for(int i = 0; OpenFormsReference.Count; i++){
  Form currentForm = OpenFormsReference[i];

  if(currentForm is uniqueFormClassName){
    foundForm = true
    //do stuff with it like giving Focus
  }

  if(!foundForm){
    //You did not find a form instance
    //Do stuff like creating and showing it
  }

}
```

You could also store a refrence to "UniqueForm" in "mainForm". But doing so means you have to manage the cleaning of the variable too.

You might be able to coblle something together by changing the Visibiltiy or Hidden attribute. But I was told *never* to use those on Forms level.